# NSPanel is not clickable, but keyboard events work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSPanel which is not clickable. Keyboard events work, but I can't click on buttons, or select a text field, or even the maximize/minimize buttons on top left.

What could be the reason ?

The panel is build in interface builder and loaded with this line:

```
[NSApp beginSheet:panel modalForWindow:mainWindow modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it appear as a sheet or a regular panel? I had similar problem when a sheet window had the "**Visible at Launch**" box checked. Uncheck it, try again. Also, make sure **mainWindow != nil**.

Comment: Visible at launch is disabled. Where is mainWindow setting ?

Comment: mainWindow is the parameter you pass to the [NSApp beginSheet:modalForWindow:...]. You might have a nil pointer here.